# SQL Server CDC - Issue dealing with schema changes

Tags: sql-server, cdc

Our customers have a requirement to track data changes in a database, who did it and when (held in additional columns).

Previously we have achieved this via a trigger on each table that inserts into a mirror audit table. We keep this data permanently (and would only take action to archive if the data gets very large)

The Change Data Capture Functions build into SQL server seem to be very similar ie. sys.sp_cdc_enable_table.

The issue is that after a table change (add new column) we would need to turn off the existing data tracking and then turn it on again pointing at a different CDC table. Unfortunately, sys.sp_cdc_disable_table drops the original tracking table – is there any simple way to prevent this behavior (ideally I would just like it to be left in place)? I can't seem to rename the table through SQL Server Management Studio.

I appreciate we could write scripts etc. to copy the data but this would more effort than the original approach. I suspect we may have to stick with the original approach.

I appreciate this is not quite what CDC was designed for but it if we could get it to work it would simplify our system and save some effort.

Comment: Last I checked, CDC doesn't have an easy way for you to find out "who" (if it's not already being inserted into the changes themselves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible - this is not what CDC is intended for.

The CDC approach is better than the trigger approach - it's more performant and more reliable because it's reading directly from the Transaction Log. Under normal operation CDC will only maintain a history of about 5 days but the purge is driven from a SQL Agent job which you can disable. However I think the best approach would be for you to periodically export from the CDC table into your existing audit table (which you said you probably weren't prepared to do).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. We have a few options so we will evaluate those.